# Featured questions not appearing on main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tags, code-review-se

I've tagged two questions on Code Review [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). This should cause the question to appear on the main site's featured area, but they aren't.

[image: Tagged questions]

[image: Featured area]

[What should our elevator pitch be?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/233/110) - Asked March 8 about 9 pm EST
[What should our logo and site design look like?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/110) - Asked Jan. 20

UPDATE: As of 17:45 EST March 9, the more recent question is on the meta ad. The older one is subject to the 30 day limit.

Answer (score 5):

When did you do this? The meta list is cached for an hour, so it can update no more often than that.

Additionally, the meta house ad will not feature questions created more than 30 days ago any more. I suppose I could relax this for things tagged featured.

Comment: Last night, about 9:00 Eastern.

Comment: @michael I changed it so the questions tagged [featured] are immune to this 30 day check. However, be aware that we automatically remove the featured tag from any meta posts after a certain number of days, too, to prevent the list from being stale for months.